# How to reference NAMEDATALEN in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I plan to embed SQL into my C-code using the PostgreSQL SPI, and I would like to the reference NAMEDATALEN const, so my code will be flexible enough to change with the database.

Is there a `#include <>` I can put in my C-code to reference this const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer referenced from: [Complete C-type Table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-TYPE-TABLE) *(PostgreSQL v.9.1)*

```
----------------------------------
| SQL Type | C Type | Defined In |
----------------------------------
|   name   |  Name  | postgres.h |
----------------------------------
```

It looks as though I need to do the following, to achieve my goal...

```
 #include <postgres.h>

 //char my_name[NAMEDATALEN];  // Theoretically, this should also be valid.
 Name my_name;
```

**EDIT:** After some more digging, I was able to prove my hunch correct.

---

Pasted from [`postgres.h`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/postgres_8h_source.html)

```
00047 #include "c.h"
```

Pasted from [`c.h`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/c_8h_source.html)

```
00443 /*
00444  * Representation of a Name: effectively just a C string, but null-padded to
00445  * exactly NAMEDATALEN bytes.  The use of a struct is historical.
00446  */
00447 typedef struct nameData
00448 {
00449     char        data[NAMEDATALEN];
00450 } NameData;
00451 typedef NameData *Name;
```